# Master Data Services: Bypass member Name and Code input?

Tags: master-data-services

We're on MDS 2008 R2. Does anyone know of a way that we can make MDS automatically generate a Name and Code, though the MDS interface when a data entry person clicks on the new member button, so they can just go on and enter the pertinent info. Data entry staff shouldn't be having to come up with name and codes for records, at least for us.

I can't see how to do this, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Default value action - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633870(v=sql.105).aspx#Actions - to default a value for the Code. Names are not mandatory. However, you can use the same Default value action to generate a Name as well. The way Code defaulting works has changed somewhat with MDS 2012 but as long as you are on 2008R2 you shouldn't have to worry about that.